# Navigate to new screen on button click SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a login screen and wish to navigate to a new screen when the Login button is clicked.
I did try to wrap the button and the entire screen layout under NavigationView and embedded the button in a Navigation Link.
I am unable to figure out how to show the new screen when the button is clicked. Following is the code for the login screen.

```
ZStack {
        Color.red
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)


        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 180.0) {
            Text("SwiftUI")
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .bold()
            .padding()

            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 25) {
                TextField("Username", text: $userName)
                    .padding(.all)
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .cornerRadius(10)

                TextField("Password", text: $userPassword)
                    .padding(.all)
                    .background(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)

                Toggle(isOn: $isFirstTimeUser) {
                    Text("First Time User")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .bold()
                        .padding(.horizontal, -10)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                }.padding(.horizontal, 17)

                Button(action: {
                    if self.userName.count <= 5 {
                        self.isAlertShown = true
                    } else {


                    }
                })
                    {
                        Text(isFirstTimeUser ? "SignUp" : "Login")
                            .fontWeight(.medium)
                            .font(.title)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                    }.padding()
                .background(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                    .alert(isPresented: $isAlertShown) {
                        () -> Alert in
                        Alert(title: Text("UserName Invalid"), message: Text("Username has to be more than 5 characters"), dismissButton:.default(Text("Got that!")))
                    }
            }.padding(.horizontal, 17)

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is possible approach

1) Add link tag state variable to your View

```
@State private var current: Int? = nil
```

2) Wrap your view hierarchy into `NavigationView` to make possible `NavigationLink` to work

3) Add tagged `NavigationLink` above your button

```
NavigationLink(destination: YourDestinationViewHere(), tag: 1, selection: $current) {
    EmptyView()
}
```

4) Add link tag selection to button action

```
Button(action: {
    if self.userName.count <= 5 {
        self.isAlertShown = true
    } else {
        self.current = 1 // this activates NavigationLink with specified tag
    }
})
```