# Change window size based on NavigationView in a SwiftUI macOS app

Tags: macos, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm using SwiftUI for a Mac app where the main window contains a NavigationView. This NavigationView contains a sidebar list. When an item in the sidebar is selected, it changes the view displayed in the detail view. The views presented in the detail view are different sizes which should cause the size of the window to change when they are displayed. However, when the detail view changes size the window does not change size to accommodate the new detail view.

How can I make the window size change according to the size of the NavigationView?

My example code for the app is below:

```
import SwiftUI

struct View200: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("200").font(.title)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 400)
            .background(Color(.systemRed))
    }
}

struct View500: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("500").font(.title)
            .frame(width: 500, height: 300)
            .background(Color(.systemBlue))
    }
}

struct ViewOther: View {
    let item: Int
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(item)").font(.title)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
            .background(Color(.systemGreen))
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {

    let item: Int

    var body: some View {
        switch item {
        case 2:
            return AnyView(View200())
        case 5:
            return AnyView(View500())
        default:
            return AnyView(ViewOther(item: item))
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
             List {
                 ForEach(1...10, id: \.self) { index in
                     NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: index)) {
                         Text("Link \(index)")
                     }
                 }
             }
             .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

And here is what the example app looks like when the detail view changes size:

[image: screen recording]

Answer (score 5):

Here is demo of possible approach that works. I did it on one different view, because you will need to redesign your solution to adopt it.

Demo

[image: SwiftUI animate window frame]

1) The view requiring window animated resize

```
struct ResizingView: View {
    public static let needsNewSize = Notification.Name("needsNewSize")

    @State var resizing = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.resizing.toggle()
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Self.needsNewSize, object: 
                    CGSize(width: self.resizing ? 800 : 400, height: self.resizing ? 350 : 200))
            }, label: { Text("Resize") } )
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 400, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 200, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

2) Window's owner (in this case `AppDelegate`)

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI
import Combine

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var window: NSWindow!
    var subscribers = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

        let contentView = ResizingView()

        window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300), // just default
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        window.center()
        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
        window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: ResizingView.needsNewSize)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: {_ in}) { [unowned self] notificaiton in
                if let size = notificaiton.object as? CGSize {
                    var frame = self.window.frame
                    let old = self.window.contentRect(forFrameRect: frame).size

                    let dX = size.width - old.width
                    let dY = size.height - old.height

                    frame.origin.y -= dY // origin in flipped coordinates
                    frame.size.width += dX
                    frame.size.height += dY
                    self.window.setFrame(frame, display: true, animate: true)
                }
            }
            .store(in: &subscribers)
    }
    ...
```

Comment: In your example you use a Button to post the notification. But in my example I use a List where each item is a NavigationLink that changes the view. So I'm not sure how to use your approach for my particular example. Note - I updated my question with a link to a YouTube video that shows a screen recording of my example app.

Comment: NavigationLink can be activated programmatically, see [here by tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58912719/navigate-to-new-screen-on-button-click-swiftui/58913518?r=SearchResults&s=9|33.8175#58913518), [here by isActive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59276161/how-can-i-use-navigation-in-alert-using-swiftui/59281485?r=SearchResults&s=20|21.3536#59281485)

Comment: The sidebar in my example stops working if I use the `tag` and `selection` parameters with the NavigationLink.

Comment: Another approach I tried was to post the notification from within the switch statement in the DetailView. But this gives a warning about "NSHostingView is being laid out reentrantly while rendering its SwiftUI content. This is not supported and the current layout pass will be skipped."

Comment: I updated my example code but I still don't see how to use your approach with a `List` and `NavigationLink`.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. Should be noted that you don't *have* to create the content view and window inside AppDelegate, if you're using the SwiftUI window template. You can use `let window = NSApp.mainWindow` to get a reference to the window inside AppDelegate. That's just to get the frame -- the NotificationCenter code doesn't care where `ResizingView` is used -- you can just embed it in the SwiftUI `WindowGroup` (or anywhere else in the hierarchy) normally.

Thanks Asperi for the great answer!

Comment: Code example using the SwiftUI structure: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65047047/10872536

Answer (score 4):

Asperi's answer works for me, but the animation is not working on Big Sur 11.0.1, Xcode 12.2. Thankfully, the animation works if you wrap it in an NSAnimationContext:

```
NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ context in
    context.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeIn)
    window!.animator().setFrame(frame, display: true, animate: true)
}, completionHandler: {
})
```

Also it should be mentioned that `ResizingView` and `window` don't have to be initialized inside AppDelegate; you can continue using SwiftUI's App struct:

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {

    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ResizingView()
        }
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var window: NSWindow?
    var subscribers = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ notification: Notification) {
        self.window = NSApp.mainWindow
    }

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        setupResizeNotification()
    }

    private func setupResizeNotification() {
        NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: ResizingView.needsNewSize)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: {_ in}) { [unowned self] notificaiton in
                if let size = notificaiton.object as? CGSize, self.window != nil {
                    var frame = self.window!.frame
                    let old = self.window!.contentRect(forFrameRect: frame).size
                    let dX = size.width - old.width
                    let dY = size.height - old.height
                    frame.origin.y -= dY // origin in flipped coordinates
                    frame.size.width += dX
                    frame.size.height += dY
                    NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ context in
                        context.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeIn)
                        window!.animator().setFrame(frame, display: true, animate: true)
                    }, completionHandler: {
                    })
                }
            }
            .store(in: &subscribers)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

the following will not solve your problem, but might (with some extra work), lead you to a solution.

I did not have much to investigate further, but it's possible to overwrite the setContentSize method in NSWindow (by subclassing of course). That way you can override the default behavior, which is setting the window frame without an animation.

The problem you will have to figure out is the fact that for complex views such as yours, the setContentSize method is called repeatedly, causing the animation not to work properly.

The following example works fine, but that's because we are dealing with a very simple view:

[image]

```swift
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var window: NSWindow!


    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
        let contentView = ContentView()

        // Create the window and set the content view. 
        window = AnimatableWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        window.center()
        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
        window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
}


class AnimatableWindow: NSWindow {
    var lastContentSize: CGSize = .zero

    override func setContentSize(_ size: NSSize) {

        if lastContentSize == size { return } // prevent multiple calls with the same size

        lastContentSize = size

        self.animator().setFrame(NSRect(origin: self.frame.origin, size: size), display: true, animate: true)
    }

}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var flag = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Change") {
                self.flag.toggle()
            }
        }.frame(width: self.flag ? 100 : 300 , height: 200)
    }
}
```

Comment: As you alluded to in your answer, this approach does not work well for my example. The sidebar disappears when the ThreeView is displayed.