# Animate NSWindow's size change based on SwiftUI changes

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, appkit

By default, an `NSWindow` that hosts a SwiftUI view will automatically resize to fit the size of the view if/when it changes. However, if the changes are animated, the window jumps to the final size without animating. Is there a way to animate the window size along with the content?

I've tried this with and without SwiftUI's lifecycle. I'v also tried calling the `toggle` method with `NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup`

[image: Gif showing SwiftUI view animating but window jumping to final position without animating]

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isExpanded = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(isExpanded ? "Close" : "Open", action: toggleExpand)
            
            if isExpanded {
                ForEach(0..<5) { count in
                    Text("\(count). Some Item")
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .fixedSize()
    }
    
    func toggleExpand() {
        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1)) { isExpanded.toggle() }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59387212/12299030?