# How do I navigate between views using a button in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am in a login page and when I press the login button, if the login was completed without errors I want to navigate to a new view, if the login failed I want to stay on the same view. Here is my code:

```
struct LogIn: View {

    @State var mesaj = ""
    @State private var email = ""
    @State private var password = ""
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                // EMAIL
                TextField("E-mail", text: $email).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())

                // PASSWORD
                TextField("Password", text: $password).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())

                // this is the login button
                Button(action: {
                    loginRequest(link: "https://someapi.com", email: self.email, password: self.password) // this is the login request
                    let seconds = 5.0
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + seconds) {
                        self.mesaj = message
                        if message == "You are now logged in"
                        {
                            // here I want to navigate to a new view
                        }
                    }
                }) {
                    Text("LogIn")
                }
                Text(mesaj)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Navigate to new screen on button click SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58912719/navigate-to-new-screen-on-button-click-swiftui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-arrange your views, such that

instead of going directly to your LogIn view, have an intermediate view with something like this:

```
struct PreLogIn: View {

@State var loggedInSuccess = false // that you pass into the LogIn() view
// or 
@EnvironmentObject var model: Model  // with a @Published var loggedInSuccess = false 

var body: some View {
     Group {
        if model.loggedInSuccess {
            YourNextView()
        }
        else {
            LogIn()
        }
    }
}
}
```

then in your LogIn() view button action:

```
model.loggedInSuccess = true
```